# Parallel matrix multiplication in Java with streams

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix

[This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774384/multiply-2-double-matrices-using-streams) highlights how to do matrix multiplication using Java's stream.

With Java streams, there is a new way to enable concurrent threading with the Java's parallel stream.

**ParallelMatrixMultiplication.java**

```
  public Matrix multiply(Matrix v) {
    return new Matrix(Arrays.stream(this.m).parallel()
                            .map(row -> IntStream.range(0, v.m[0].length)
                            .mapToDouble(i -> IntStream.range(0, v.m.length)
                            .mapToDouble(j -> row[j] * v.m[j][i]).sum())
                            .toArray())
                            .toArray(double[][]::new));
  }
```

As you can see, I simply added the `.parallel()` method.

This function works fine as a noticeable speed up is seen for larger matrices.

**I'm curious then, is there a way to optimize or speed this function up further?**

Comment: Certainly it can be done faster, since there is no cache optimization by loop tiling here. But I wouldn't know how to do that with streams. Are non-stream implementations allowed?

Comment: Non stream is okay as well, just that I'm not familiar with concurrent processing i.e. fork/join and .parallel() was the easiest to implement.